# When i try to sign up using my app its says Client_Error

Tags: php, client

so I contacted my hosting this what they said

I'm sorry but we do not support Applications related queries. You need to contact your App developer since this is an App related issue.

but my app developer said
For signup issue:
This is not related to the app. It is your hosting that is causing this problem.

> data": "document.cookie = "humans_21909=1";
> document.location.reload(true)" "originalError": [Error:
> Request failed with status code 409],  "problem": "CLIENT_ERROR",
> "status": 409,

pls i need help

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409 might help you. It's an unusual error. But we can't help you at all really because all you gave us is a random error message, with no accompanying code or any description of how the error happened. You'll need to put a lot more information into your question. Remember we know nothing about anything that is happening unless you tell us specifically.

Comment: As you're new to StackOverflow (welcome!) 
I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.